# Is it possible for a metal plate to move when a beam of light rays is incident on it?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

When a beam of light rays fall on a metal surface at an angle, shouldn't the electrons get ejected( due to transfer of energy and momentum ) just like in the case of photoelectric effect? Is it possible for the metal plate to move ? And what will happen if it has a perfectly reflecting surface?

Comment: Yes, see; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail

Comment: Got it ,Thanks!

Comment: This is several questions.  to answer the photoelectric part, see  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309991/does-the-photoelectric-effet-occurs-only-with-metals